# What is the meaning of the mentioned query?

Tags: c#, sql

If I had the table "CustomerDetails" than what is the below query explains??

```
var details = (from data in entity.CustomerDetails where (data.CustomerId == CustId && data.CustomerProjectID == CustProjId) select data).FirstOrDefault();
```

Share the exact meaning. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about you start explaining it and ask help when stuck? You presumably have a wrong feeling that stackoverflow community does job for you for free (while it does not).

Comment: Read the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt693024.aspx)

Comment: Maybe try and understand it first. Don't expect every question SO will solve it for you.

Comment: Hi guys. Thanks for your reply. Sure I'll mind in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That query selects the `data` from the `CustomerDetails` table where the `CustomerId` equals the given `CustId` and the `CustomerProjectID` equals the given `CustProjId`. It then returns the first element from the set that returns.

I *personally* find it easier to use LINQ Expressions like so:

```
var details = entity.CustomerDetails
    .FirstOrDefault(cust => 
        cust.CustomerId == CustId && 
        cust.CustomerProjectID == CustProjId
    );
```

Comment: this is good practice to write linq query.. this does works well and also allow to understand faster and easier to new commerce like u